# javascript - scope of !! (bang bang) in Boolean coercion

Tags: javascript, boolean, type-coercion

I have a strange result when using `!!`:

```
["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 // true
!!(["a"].indexOf("b") === -1) //true
!!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 // false
!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 //false
```

Obviously the first and second results are as expected, but the other two seem strange, right? I can't seem to find a reason why the second and third statements aren't equivalent, and I certainly can't understand how the third and fourth statements can possibly have the same Boolean value.

My guess was that `!!["a"]` is evaluated to `true` before the rest of the statement is evaluated, but then why wouldn't you get a `TypeError` for `true.indexOf("b")`??

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how operator precedence works, but I would like to understand what is going on here if someone is able to explain.

Comment: `(!!(["a"].indexOf("b"))) === -1` would also be false, if that helps clarify... Neither `true` nor `false` is equal in type and value to `-1`.

Comment: Yes! But that one at least makes sense because it's easy to see how it evaluates to `true === -1`, right?

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what your third example is doing.

Comment: Aha - so #3 is saying `true === -1` and #4 is saying `false === -1` and that's why they both evaluate to false. That makes sense as to why they're not the opposite of each other. So basically the ! operates only on the immediately following expression, and parens should be used to avoid this confusion. So ultimately that's not a strange result at all. Oh well...

Comment: In this case the `!!` seems redundant, as you're starting with a boolean result. If you want to invert it then yes, parentheses would be needed: `!(["a"].indexOf("b") === -1)`, but you could just rewrite as the (IMO) clearer `["a"].indexOf("b") !== -1` or `["a"].indexOf("b") > -1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe totally - this was never going to be where I ended up - I was refactoring and just noticed this and then spent 20 mins trying to figure it out. If you fancy adding an answer I'll accept it of course

Comment: You mention operator precedence, so your question is answered e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Of the three things you care about, member access is higher precedence than logical not, which is in turn higher than strict equality. The parentheses in my first comment merely clarify this relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 // false`:

["a"].indexOf("b") gives -1 then !!-1 gives true which is not strictly equal to -1 which gives false.

`!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 //false`:

["a"].indexOf("b") gives -1 then !-1 gives false which is not strictly equal to -1 which gives false.

It is worth noting here that in numeric context, used in these comparisons (and in general except you compare two strings), true is 1 and false is 0. So, even  `==` would give two falses.

Another question is [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

1. function call (["a"].indexOf("b"))
2. logical NOT(!)
3. strict equality (===)

Answer (score 1):

You should have checked the Javascript operator precedence, as can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

It shows that the logical NOT (`!`) has higher precedence than the script equality (`===`) operator.

So:

```
!!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1
```

Evaluates as:

```
(!!["a"].indexOf("b")) === -1
```

Which means `(!!-1) === -1` which is obviously false as `!!-1` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is evaluated in the following order:

```
"a" // -> "a"
["a"] // -> ["a"]
["a"].indexOf("b") // -> -1
!!["a"].indexOf("b") // -> true
!!["a"].indexOf("b") === -1 // -> false
```

so the point is that `.` evaluates before `!`.